# Why do I have idle workers when using Python multiprocessing pools?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am breaking a very large text file up into smaller chunks, and performing further processing on the chunks. For this example, let `text_chunks` be a list of lists, each list containing a section of text. The elements of `text_chunks` range in length from ~50 to ~15000. The class `ProcessedText` exists elsewhere in the code and does a large amount of subsequent processing and data classification based on the text fed to it. The different text chunks are processed into `ProcessedText` instances in parallel using code like the following:

```
def do_things_to_text(a, b):
    #pull out necessary things for ProcessedText initialization and return an instance
    print('Processing {0}'.format(a))
    return ProcessedText(a, b)

import multiprocessing as mp

#prepare inputs for starmap, pairing with list index so order can be reimposed later
pool_inputs = list(enumerate(text_chunks))

#parallel processing
pool = mp.Pool(processes=8)
results = pool.starmap_async(do_things_to_text, pool_inputs)
output = results.get()
```

The code executes successfully, but it seems that some of the worker processes created as part of the `Pool` randomly sit idle while the code runs. I track the memory usage, CPU usage, and status in `top` while the code executes.

At the beginning all 8 worker processes are engaged (status "R" in `top` and nonzero CPU usage), after ~20 entries from `text_chunks` are completed, the worker processes start to vary wildly. At times, as few as 1 worker process is running, and the others are in status "S" with zero CPU usage. I can also see from my printed output statements that `do_things_to_text()` is being called less frequently. So far I haven't been able to identify why the processes start to idle. There are plenty of entries left to process, so them sitting idle leads to time-inefficiency.

My questions are:

1. Why are these worker processes sitting idle?
2. Is there a better way to implement `multiprocessing` that will prevent this?

EDITED to ADD:
I have further characterized the problem. It is clear from the indexes I print out in `do_things_to_text()` that multiprocessing is dividing the total number of jobs into threads at every tenth index. So my console output shows Job 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 being submitted at the same time (8 processes). And some of the Jobs complete faster than others, so you might see Job 22 completed before you see Job 1 completed.

Up until this first batch of threads is completed, all processes are active with nothing idle. However, when that batch is complete, and Job 80 starts, only one process is active, and the other 7 are idle. I have not confirmed, but I believe it stays like this until the 80-series is complete.

Comment: How large is the text file? How many jobs are being submitted, i.e. `len(pool_inputs)`? How long do the processes stay idle?

Comment: @Booboo The text file size will vary, but for the example I'm presently developing with, about 8 GB. pool_inputs is presently 301 elements, but that also may vary in general application. The processes stay idle for maybe 5-10 mins I think, whereas one process usually completes in around 1 min when not idle.

I have also made some new discoveries that I will be updating the original question with.

Comment: I can't say for sure what the issue is; I can only make some recommendations that would better utilize memory. Whether they would clear up all your issues is a big question mark.

Comment: @Booboo All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: A couple of comments: (1) See my `compute_chunksize` function in my answer below. This is essentially the function `starmap_asynch` will use to break up `pool_inputs` into "chunks" based on the size of the pool and the size of `pool_inputs`. Given for example a pool size of 8 and 300 elements in `pool_inputs`, a `chunksize` value of 10 will be computed. It will therefore put the first 10 elements of `pool_inputs` on the first process's input queue, the next 10 elements on the second process's input queue. This is why you see the initial jobs printed as 0, 10, 20, etc. (more...)

Comment: (2) I don't see why you need to use `enumerate` for creating `pool_inputs` because `starmap_asynch` will return all the results in the same order as the input of the passed iterable (`pool_inputs` in this case). Thus, the ith element of `output` will correspond to the ith element of `pool_inputs`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some recommendations for better memory utilization:

I don't know how `text_chunks` is created but ultimately you end up with 8GB worth of strings in `pool_inputs`. Ideally, you would have a generator function, for example `make_text_chunks`, that yields the individual "text chunks" that formerly comprised the `text_chunks` iterable (if `text_chunks` is already such a generator expression, then you are all set). The idea is to *not* create all 8GB worth of data at once but only as the data is needed. With this strategy you can no longer use `Pool` method `starmap_asynch`; we will be using [`Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool%20imap#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap). This method, unlike `startmap_asynch`, will iteratively submit jobs in `chunksize` chunks and you can process the results as they become available (although that doesn't seem to be an issue).

```
def make_text_chunks():
    # logic goes here to generate the next chunk
    yield text_chunk


def do_things_to_text(t):
    # t is now a tuple:
    a, b = t
    #pull out necessary things for ProcessedText initialization and return an instance
    print('Processing {0}'.format(a))
    return ProcessedText(a, b)


import multiprocessing as mp

# do not turn into a list!
pool_inputs = enumerate(make_text_chunks())

def compute_chunksize(n_jobs, poolsize):
    """
    function to compute chunksize as is done by Pool module
    """
    if n_jobs == 0:
        return 0
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(n_jobs, poolsize * 4)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

#parallel processing
# number of jobs approximately
# don't know exactly without turning pool_inputs into a list, which would be self-defeating
N_JOBS = 300
POOLSIZE = 8
CHUNKSIZE = compute_chunksize(N_JOBS, POOLSIZE)
with mp.Pool(processes=POOLSIZE) as pool:
    output = [result for result in pool.imap(do_things_to_text, pool_inputs, CHUNKSIZE)]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is certainly worth considering for this issue, but unfortunately in the current iteration```text_chunks``` has to be read into memory entirely because I'm having to split the original text file at fixed intervals, then recombine everything afterwards to have it split by delimiter instead.

I will keep in mind for future re-writes just reading the text file into memory and doing a delimiter split from the beginning, which should allow me to ```imap```.

Comment: According to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async), `map_async` also can accept iterable as "inputs" and `chunksize`.

Comment: @Brainor Of course, it can accept *iterables*. However, if that *iterable* does not implement the `__len__` method, then `map_async` converts the *iterable* into a `list` so that it can get its length. And it does this so that it if `chunksize=None` is specified (this is the default value if no *chunksize* argument is passed), then it can compute a *chunksize* based on the number of elements in the *iterable* and the pool size. But even if a *chunksize* value is specified, it will still convert the *iterable* into a list so that there is no *lazy evaluation*. (more...)

Comment: @Brainor Also, the results from `map_async` are returned as a `list`, so you cannot iterate the results one at a time to save memory as you can with `imap` and `imap_unordered`.

Comment: @Booboo `map_async` returns _result_ as a `list` with `result.get()` method which is not too different from `imap` IMHO; `result: IMapIterator` from `imap` also stores results as a list-like object in its *_items* attributes. But yes you are right:) `map_async` will turn  the _iterable_ input into a list if it doesn't have `__len__` attribute, which will be very expensive compared to `imap`. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Brainor Yes, I should have said "`map_async` returns result as a list with `result.get()`."